# Replace FragmentTransaction error in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to switch Fragments, replace one with another.

I have the main frame layout -  `R.layout.fragment_container`.
I can add the first Fragment successfully but when I try to change fragments I get an error.
When go to debug mode I do go to my onPageNavigationSelected function but have an exception

```
package com.book1;

import com.book1.Page1_fragment.onPageNavigationListener;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
                    implements onPageNavigationListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_conteiner);

        Page1_fragment page1 = new Page1_fragment();
        page1.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, page1).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageNavigationSelected(String back_forward) {
        Page2_fragment page2 = new Page2_fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, page2);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();       
    }
```

my fragment code :

```
package com.book1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Page1_fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
                            implements AnimationListener{
    Animation move;
    ImageView big_dood;         
    onPageNavigationListener callback_page_navigation;

    public interface onPageNavigationListener{
        public void onPageNavigationSelected(String back_forward);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container   ,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        big_dood = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.big_bood);
        //ImageView black_hear_dood = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.black_hear_dood);

        move=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.move_rigth);
        move.setAnimationListener(this);

        final ImageButton pop = (ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pop);
        pop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pop.startAnimation(move);
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Animation Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        ImageButton forward =(ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.forward);
        forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callback_page_navigation.onPageNavigationSelected("page2");
                //callback_page_navigation.onPageNavigationSelected("forward");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            callback_page_navigation = (onPageNavigationListener)activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+" must implement onPageNavigationListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
    {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (animation == move) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Animation Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
    {}
}
```

My log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.book1, PID: 22241  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.book1.MainActivity@427ba210 must implement onPageNavigationListener
    at com.book1.Page2_fragment.onAttach(Page2_fragment.java:87)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.book1.MainActivity@427ba210 must implement onPageNavigationListener  
    at com.book1.Page2_fragment.onAttach(Page2_fragment.java:87)
```

The exception is being thrown in the `OnAttach()` method in `Page2_fragment`.

You have only shown us `Page1_fragment` but I will guess that you also define an Interface that the parent Activity must implement. and that you also called that Interface `onPageNavigationListener`.

The issue you are having is that there are now 2 Interfaces called `onPageNavigationListener`:

```
com.book1.Page1_fragment.onPageNavigationListener
    and
com.book1.Page2_fragment.onPageNavigationListener
```

Since you only imported the first one, you do not actually implement the one that `Page2_fragment` requires. When your second Fragment tries to cast the parent Activity as a valid Listener you get your ClassCastException.

You have two choices. You can either:

- Rename the second Interface and its method so that they do not clash with the first Fragment's Interface.
- Make one (optional abstract) parent Fragment that defines one Interface. Extend that Fragment in both your PageX_fragments and then in your Activity `import com.book1.ParentPageFragment.OnPageNavigationListener`.

In the second option both Fragments will call the same method and it will be up to the Activity to work out which Fragment is calling it and what, if anything, to do differently.

Side note: You should name your Interfaces starting with an upper-case letter. `OnPageNavigationListener` not 'onPageNavigationListener`.

Comment: Thanks I did your second choice , with the abstract class